# Is data scaling necessary in mars regression?

Tags: r, mars

I am very new to data science. Something struck me about Mars regression. The dataset is not on the same scale, so some columns are %, others are integers. I want to do clustering before doing Mars regression. I know I need to scale the data for this. But I don't know if I should apply the Mars regression to the scaled data or the original data? Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clear singular answer to that question. There are times where it may be necessary, but in general MARS regressions are pretty flexible. So, the questions comes down to this model, or more accurately SET of models.

If you are going to do clustering which requires standardization, then continue on with your standardized variables in the MARS regression. It does make interpretation more difficult, but if you use a transformer method to do the work, you can de-standardize too.

It should not hurt your model to use standardized data.

**EDIT TO ADDRESS COMMENT:**

*Note:* I used the 'transformation' to describe standardizing the data, just a little linguistic sleight of hand.

> How can I understand that standardized values ​​harm a model? With r2 and gcv values? –

**Standardize Variables Do Not Harm Regression Models**

You can prove this to yourself by building two models and seeing what happens.

**Example:**

The coefficients will change for sure (because the magnitude of the values has changed so more or less X is necessary to create y).

However, the actually quality of the model is unchanged. A regressions ability to capture patterns is about understanding variation between data points both within and across variables (This is true with most types ML models).

In the case of a regression, which is unit-less, this means no change in accuracy or predictiveness occurs when you scale & center (which I will show below). However, in some types of models, the predictive capability is hugely improved by standardizing.

To prove this for regressions you can do a simple experiment:

```
require(earth)
data(mtcars) #sample data

Standard_cars<-data.frame(scale(mtcars, center = TRUE, scale=TRUE))

#model without standardizing
summary(lm(mpg~cyl + disp+ hp, data = mtcars))

#model with standardizing
summary(lm(mpg~cyl + disp+ hp, data = Standard_cars))
```

You can see from the results below

**Without Standardization:**

```
    Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.0889 -2.0845 -0.7745  1.3972  6.9183 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 34.18492    2.59078  13.195 1.54e-13 ***
cyl         -1.22742    0.79728  -1.540   0.1349    
disp        -0.01884    0.01040  -1.811   0.0809 .  
hp          -0.01468    0.01465  -1.002   0.3250    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.055 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7679,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.743 
F-statistic: 30.88 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 5.054e-09
```

**Adjusted R-squared:**  0.743
**p-value:** 5.054e-09

**With Standardization:**

```
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, data = Standard_cars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.6784 -0.3459 -0.1285  0.2318  1.1479 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept) -3.821e-17  8.961e-02   0.000   1.0000  
cyl         -3.637e-01  2.363e-01  -1.540   0.1349  
disp        -3.874e-01  2.139e-01  -1.811   0.0809 .
hp          -1.670e-01  1.667e-01  -1.002   0.3250  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5069 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7679,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.743 
F-statistic: 30.88 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 5.054e-09
```

**Adjusted R-squared:**  0.743
**p-value:** 5.054e-09

There are no changes in the predictive capabilities or the confidence we in this model, just the coefficients. However, if you use mean/sd standardization you can revert to real-world values pretty easily.

You might wonder if this is true also for MARS:

```
summary(earth(mpg~cyl + disp+ hp, data = mtcars))


Call: earth(formula=mpg~cyl+disp+hp, data=mtcars)

              coefficients
(Intercept)     20.7581870
h(140.8-disp)    0.1564930
h(disp-140.8)   -0.0255449

Selected 3 of 8 terms, and 1 of 3 predictors
Termination condition: RSq changed by less than 0.001 at 8 terms
Importance: cyl-unused, disp, hp-unused
Number of terms at each degree of interaction: 1 2 (additive model)
GCV 6.844552    RSS 155.9274    GRSq 0.8174584    RSq 0.8615267
summary(earth(mpg~cyl + disp+ hp, data = Standard_cars))


Call: earth(formula=mpg~cyl+disp+hp, data=Standard_cars)

                   coefficients
(Intercept)           0.1107629
h(-0.725535-disp)     3.2181355
h(disp- -0.725535)   -0.5253080

Selected 3 of 8 terms, and 1 of 3 predictors
Termination condition: RSq changed by less than 0.001 at 8 terms
Importance: cyl-unused, disp, hp-unused
Number of terms at each degree of interaction: 1 2 (additive model)
GCV 0.18843    RSS 4.292672    GRSq 0.8174584    RSq 0.8615267
```

Again different coefficients, but same `GRSq` & `RSq` so, it is safe to assume that the model you built on standardized data is equivalent to the same model built on unstandardized data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I don't understand what you mean by transformation. Graphics vs. Are you talking about displaying standardized data as original data in your drawings? When I tried it with scaled data, the r2 values ​​of the models were high and the gcv values ​​were low. Do you think I should accept this as a satisfactory result? How can I understand that standardized values ​​harm a model? With r2 and gcv values?

Comment: Thanks again, it was very informative for me. I used the scale() function in r for scaling. As far as I understand, this function does average/sd. It was in negative values. I experimented with both scaled and non-scaled data and looked at the importance of the variables. As you said, there is not much difference, only the nsubsets criterion is different. As a result, a shorter equation is formed. Negative values ​​occurred in the equations of standardized data, but this is a normal situation as far as I understand. This is an article you know about what you said, etc. do you have it?